# Why do Chrome/Safari include the Origin header in Access-Control-Request-Headers?

Tags: cross-domain, cors

This question is like a followup to [Why are non-custom headers included in Access-Control-Request-Headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330302/why-non-custom-headers-in-access-control-request-headers)

During a CORS preflight request, both Chrome and Safari include the `Origin` header in the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header. They ignore this header, in the sense that Origin doesn't need to be in the corresponding Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header. And while the CORS spec doesn't define Origin as a simple header, there are other headers, such as `User-Agent`, that aren't defined as simple headers and yet aren't included in Access-Control-Request-Headers. Firefox does not include the Origin header in Access-Control-Request-Headers.

So my question is: why do Chrome & Safari include the `Origin` header in `Access-Control-Request-Headers`, especially since it has no effect? My guess is because they are both based on WebKit, but I'm looking for an answer that digs deeper into why this behavior exists at all.