# Using ajaxError global handler to display HTTP status code 401 details

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, error-handling

I'm trying to add a global error handler, and first test was with a call where I purposefully caused error code 401 due to no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

I've used Chrome to show the error and verify that it is thrown but I can't figure out how to use the handler to display that message.

The `jqxhr.status` is `0` and `jqxhr.statusText` is `"error"` and the `thrownError` is an empty string.

Using Chrome, I couldn't find the code and message in any of the function variables. Is there a way to show the code and message seen in Chrome debug mode?

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
    alert("Global Error Catch. Error of " + thrownError + " at url = " + settings.url + " event type of " + settings.type
        + " with event data of " + event.data + " and event type of " + event.type + " and event target of " + event.target
        + " and the jqXHR.status is " + jqxhr.status + " and jqXHR.statusText is " + jqxhr.statusText
        + " and the jqXHR.responseText  is " + jqxhr.responseText + " and jqXHR.responseXML  is " + jqxhr.responseXML);
});
```

Looking at the code again I noticed that the button click event uses `jQuery.when()` to find some input variable values before finally making the ajax call that triggers the 401. Could that be why `ajaxError` is not showing the error in `thrownError`?

**Update**
After further testing this is not related to the `jQuery.when()`. But could this be related to the fact I'm making a cross domain ajax request?

Fiddler can at least see a `401 unauthorized` response and when using Chrome debug mode I can see both the `401 unauthorized` and the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error message. But is that only sent back to the calling code if I do it myself in the web api? I assumed since it was visible in both Fiddler and Chrome it should be somewhere visible to the global `ajaxError` handler.

**Update2**
After more testing this does be related to the nature of a CORS request and not how I've used the global error catching. I might need to create a separate question on that specific topic.

I have also tried the code below and `jqXHR.status` returns 0 and `textStatus = "error"` and `errorThrown=""`. I think this is similar to the question posted [here on status code 0 for a 401 in fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844307/ajax-status-code-returns-0-when-fiddler-detects-401?rq=1) but I don't see a solution posted. I will searching for posts similar to that and if I find one I will include it as an answer.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (jqXHR.status == 401) {
            alert("Error 401 : " + textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
        } else {
            alert("Error: " + textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `thrownError` parameter within `.ajaxError` handler .

Could alternatively use `statusCode` option of `$.ajaxSetup()`

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  statusCode: {
    401: function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I updated the original question to include that `thrownError` is an empty string. I also added a note about how this test case uses `jQuery.when()` in case that is a factor.

Comment: @pretzelb What are response headers from server ?

Comment: According to Fiddler the response headers is "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized"

Comment: @pretzelb What does `jqxhr.getAllResponseHeaders()` log at `console` ? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330302/why-non-custom-headers-in-access-control-request-headers , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Comment: What is the expected response ? Is `alert()` called using `js` at post ?

Comment: The `jqxhr.getAllResponseHeaders()` returns empty string. But it might be related to CORS since IE is showing different behavior. I'm going to need to test more. What a mess. The goal is to use a global error handler that can show meaningful messages. In this case it would be the 401 and or the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Comment: @pretzelb Using `stausCode` , you should be able to alert `"401 Unauthorized"`

Comment: I have not tested your sample with statusCode because in the documentation for ajaxSetup  they `strongly recommend against using this API`. The focus of this question is to determine how to use `ajaxError` as a global handler. Either I'm using it incorrectly or this first test case involving CORS won't work.

Comment: @pretzelb fwiw, have not found that using `$.ajaxSetup()` causes issues, here. You could also pass the `statusCode` object to individual `$.ajax()` calls